# Android: get sensor data from different threads

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sensors

I have to develop an Android application for educational purposes.
This application uses a smartphone's hardware sensors, especially the accelerometer.
The application must be made ​​up of several "modules"(which could be for example background services), which all need to access to the same data from the accelerometer in real time, so that each module can use the data to make its own calculations.
For example, suppose I have an activity/an user interface, from which I can choose which services I want to start. 
For simplicity, suppose I have just two services, and I can choose to start just the first one, just the second one or both.
The first service reads data from the accelerometer and writes all of them into a text file; 
the second service, instead, uses accelerometer's data to calculate the magnitude of the acceleration and, if it is greater than a given threshold, it writes the amplitude in another file, otherwise it does nothing.

How can I do to make that the two services share the same data?
Should I put the data in a buffer or something like that? It is possible that I have to collect accelerometer's data for a long period, for example 8/12 hours at the fastest speed.

I don't have any clue of how I can do.

Could you help me please?

Many thanks

Comment: "How can I do to make that the two services share the same data?" -- you start by getting rid of one service. In your example, there is no reason why a single service cannot both write to a file and do calculations. Whether that single service does one or both things can be controlled by the UI. Services are not general-purpose Java classes. Only create separate services when there is a clear technical reason to do so, and usually that will be because they have dramatically different lifetimes. Also, per your question title, services are not threads.

Comment: ok, do you mean that, if I get rid of one service, I should start a thread for each operation inside the service? In this case, when I start my service selecting both the operations, should I start a thread which saves data into a file and a thread which does calculation?

Comment: "I should start a thread for each operation inside the service?" -- not necessarily. Writing to the file does not have to happen in parallel with doing your calculations and writing to another file. Only use a service when you know *why* you are using a service; only use multiple parallel threads when you know *why* you are using multiple parallel threads.

Comment: ok thanks. Actually writing to the file and doing other calculations have to be done in parallel, because the professor wants that I use a circular buffer in which insert the accelerometer's data, so I have to store them from the buffer to the file before that they could be overwritten by new data. Furthermore I have to do calculations about acceleration's amplitude etc in real time, because I need this values to do real time fall detection.

Comment: "because the professor wants that I use a circular buffer" -- maintain the circular buffer in memory and only periodically write it to disk. That periodic write might use a separate thread, but that would only be after N updates to the buffer. Do *not* write to disk on every sensor reading. As it stands, your app has little chance of running 8.5 hours without a recharge, as you will be keeping the CPU on constantly. If you are attempting to perform dozens or hundreds of disk I/Os per second, you will fall behind *and* drain the battery that much faster.

Comment: ok, I see your point about the battery drain. The professor said that I could put in the buffer the acceleration's samples of the last 10 seconds and then store them into a file. If I save every 10 seconds, could I lose some samples? Should I stop sampling while writing into the file?

Comment: "If I save every 10 seconds, could I lose some samples?" -- that would depend on how you are implementing the circular buffer and how you write it out to disk. Worst-case, you can make a copy of the buffer and write out the copy while you continue updating it separately.

Comment: Thank you very much. One more question: Let's suppose that before starting sampling, I can choose the sampling speed(you know, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_*).Do you suggest that I choose the dimension of the circular buffer depending on this speed ?

Comment: "Do you suggest that I choose the dimension of the circular buffer depending on this speed ?" -- yes.

Comment: @CommonsWare Sorry, I have another question: 10 seconds of samples at SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST or SENSOR_DELAY_GAME  are a huge amount of data. If I choose the dimension of the circular buffer depending on the sensor delay, if it is equals to SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST, I could have even 1000 samples per second, right? What should I use to save these samples on a file? Maybe an AsyncTask? Sorry I'm getting confused